# Problem using subtable in IEEEtran class

Tags: tables

I am using the `IEEEtran` class with the `journal` option. I would like to insert two tables side by side, each with its respective subcaption. However, when I use the `subcaption` package I get the following result:

[image]

My code is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{subtable}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
     & \textbf{Original} & \textbf{SMOTE-Tomek} \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 0} & 11645 & 10444 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 1} & 618 & 10305 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 2} & 618 & 9976 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 3} & 682 & 11597 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 4} & 736 & 10190 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 5} & 829 & 10462 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{Client 1 balance by SMOTE-Tomek}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
     & \textbf{Original} & \textbf{SMOTE-Tomek} \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 0} & 11645 & 10444 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 1} & 618 & 10305 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 2} & 618 & 9976 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 3} & 682 & 11597 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 4} & 736 & 10190 \\ \hline
    \textbf{class 5} & 829 & 10462 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{Client 2 balance by SMOTE-Tomek}
\end{subtable}
\caption{principal}
```

\end{table}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It very much looks like the widths of the `tabular` environments exceed `0.25\textwidth`. For starters, I would make the `tabular` environments less wide by forcing a line break in the `SMOTE-Tomek` header cells.

I would also try to give the tabular material a more inviting look by using the machinery of the `booktabs` package -- specifically, the user macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` -- while getting rid of all instances of `\hline`. Finally, I'd line up the numbers on their (implicit) decimal markers, and I wouldn't use **bold-facing** in the header cells, as it's simply not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{justification=centering} % optional
\begin{subtable}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits=true]} @{}}
    \toprule
    Class & {Original} & {SMOTE-} \\ 
    & & {Tomek} \\  
    \midrule
    {0} & 11645 & 10444 \\ 
    {1} &   618 & 10305 \\ 
    {2} &   618 &  9976 \\ \addlinespace
    {3} &   682 & 11597 \\ 
    {4} &   736 & 10190 \\ 
    {5} &   829 & 10462 \\  
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Client 1 balance by SMOTE-Tomek}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits=true]} @{}}
    \toprule
    Class& {Original} & {SMOTE-} \\ 
    & & {Tomek} \\  
    \midrule
    {0} & 11645 & 10444 \\ 
    {1} &   618 & 10305 \\ 
    {2} &   618 &  9976 \\ \addlinespace
    {3} &   682 & 11597 \\ 
    {4} &   736 & 10190 \\ 
    {5} &   829 & 10462 \\  
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Client 2 balance by SMOTE-Tomek}
\end{subtable}
\caption{principal}

\end{table}

\lipsum % filler text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar as in @Mico answer (+1), but with use of the `tabularray` and `subfloat` environment as is defined in the `subcaption` package (version 3.1) and manually broken text in the column head of the last table column:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subtable]{justification=centering} % optional

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \sisetup{table-format=5,
             group-four-digits=true}
    \centering
\subfloat[Client 1 balance by SMOTE-Tomek]%
{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ c *{2}{Q[c,m, si]} },
             measure=vbox
            }
    \toprule
Class & {{{Original}}} & {{{SMOTE-\\ Tomek}}} \\
    \midrule
0   & 11645 & 10444 \\
1   &   618 & 10305 \\
2   &   618 &  9976 \\ \addlinespace
3   &   682 & 11597 \\
4   &   736 & 10190 \\
5   &   829 & 10462 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
}%
\hfil
\subfloat[Client 2 balance by SMOTE-Tomek]%
{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ c *{2}{Q[c,m, si]} },
             measure=vbox
            }
    \toprule
Class & {{{Original}}} & {{{SMOTE-\\ Tomek}}} \\
    \midrule
0   & 11645 & 10444 \\
1   &   618 & 10305 \\
2   &   618 &  9976 \\ \addlinespace
3   &   682 & 11597 \\
4   &   736 & 10190 \\
5   &   829 & 10462 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
}%
\caption{principal}
\label{tab:principal}
    \end{table}

\lipsum 
\end{document}
```